# Splitting text files based on pattern and have dynamic output file names which is embedded in the file

Tags: python, regex, text, split, python-3.7

I have text files in the following format

Country:    Cntry-190605-00001

Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings

Delimiter

Country:    Cntry-190605-00002

Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings
Readings

Delimiter

I am able to split the text file into multiple files at the delimiter with the code below. My question is how to have the output filename as Cntry-190605-00001.txt, Cntry-190605-00002.txt, Cntry-190605-00003.txt........Cntry-190605-00020.txt where Cntry - type, 190605 - date, 00008 = the incrementally sequential number for that day. (Starts over every day)?  I was thinking of using regular expression to assign the output file name but how will the date and reading identifier will change for the next output file?

Seeking solution in Python only. Thank you.

```
input_file = "Test.txt"

with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    op = []
    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():  
           op.append(line)
        if line.strip() == "Delimiter":
           output = open(input_file + '%d.txt' % i,'w')
           output.write(''.join(op))
           output.close()
           i+=1
           op = []
```

Currently my output files are

```
Test.txt1
Test.txt2
Test.txt3
```

Expected output is

```
Cntry-190605-00001.txt
Cntry-190605-00002.txt
Cntry-190605-00003.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would open a new file on a line starting with `Country` and copy everything there until `Delimiter` is found:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    copy = False
    out = None
    for line in f:
        if copy:
            _ = out.write(line)
            if line.strip() == 'Delimiter':
                out.close()
                copy = False
        elif line.strip().startswith('Country'):
            file = line.split(':', 1)[1].split()[0]
            out = open(file + '.txt', 'w')
            _ = out.write(line)
            copy = True
    if out and not out.closed:
        out.close()
```

Comment: Hi Serge, I am facing a OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Pla-190605-00001\t1.3\tPlateFormat\tEndpoint\tAbsorbance\tRaw\tFALSE\t1\t\t\t\t\t\t1\t405\t1\t12\t96\t1\t8\tNone.txt' when I run your program and the error shows in line 13, in <module> out = open(file + '.txt', 'w').

Comment: I assume then that the line starting with *Country* does not only contain `Country: Pla-190605-00001` but has additional fields. How could I guess that from your question? If you do not give all the relevant data in your question you will get answers that do not work... I have edited my post with a workaround that should accept that line.

Comment: Hi Serge! Thank you for reverting. My bad that I didn't mention it in the question. It works well. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to get the filenames from the text file itself. See if this works:

```
output_filename = ''
for line in f:
    if line.strip():  
       op.append(line)
    if(line.strip().split(:)[0] == "Country"):
       output_filename = line.split(:)[1].strip() 
    if line.strip() == "Delimiter":
       output = open(output_filename,'w')
```

Comment: As Surge suggested, after I tweaked your code a little it did the job V. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Version with `re`, with the data provided it creates two files `Cntry-190605-00001.txt` and `Cntry-190605-00002.txt` with respective data each.

```
import re

data = '''Country: Cntry-190605-00001

Readings
Readings
Readings

Delimiter

Country: Cntry-190605-00002

Readings
Readings
Readings

Delimiter'''

names = re.findall(r'Country: (Cntry-\d+-\d+)', data)

for name, p in zip(names, re.findall(r'(.*?Delimiter)\s*', data, flags=re.DOTALL)):
    with open(name + '.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(p)
```

Comment: Works well, Andrej. Thank you :)